# Why does this promise resolve with the first item in the chain instead of the last one?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to understand promises better by using them in a hobby project, but I don't understand why it's taking the value from the first `.then` of the promise chain instead of the last one. In other words, how would I run some arbitrary code in a promise, then at the end, return a value to the outside of that promise? Thanks! I expect the value 'x' but the program returns 'b'.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')

Promise.resolve('x')
  .then(function (user) {
    return Promise.resolve('c').then(function (roll) {
      return Promise.resolve('a').then(function (user) {
        return Promise.resolve('b')
      })
      .then(Promise.resolve('x'))
    })
  })
  .then(function (output) {
    console.log(output)
  })
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, not least because you haven't said what value you're getting and what value you expect. But note that the above is a great example of the Promise creation anti-pattern: There's no need for most if not all of those `Promise.resolve` calls; `then` creates a promise, which returning a value from the `then` callback resolves.

Comment: Right sorry, I'll edit it, but I am expecting x when it prints b.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by returning a value from the then callback? I thought it was suggested that you return a Promise from every `then` callback.

Comment: No, `then` does that for you.

Comment: Also, this is a simplification of the code. the promise.resolves are in place of something that actually returns a value, but at the end, I just want it to return a "constant" or some variable I got up farther in the promise chain.

Comment: You must not pass a promise (`Promise.resolve('x')`) to `then` as a callback, but a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that a promise can only be resolved once.  The rest will be ignored.  Further mutation of the resolved value is achieved by chaining `then`s.  To achieve the results you are looking for (output of `x`), your code would be:

```
    var Promise = require('bluebird')

Promise.resolve('x')
  .then(function (doesnotmatter) {
    return Promise.resolve('c').then(function (alsodoesnotmatter) {
      return Promise.resolve('a').then(function (noneofthismatters) {
        return Promise.resolve('b')
      })
      .then(function(){return 'x'})
    })
  })
  .then(function (output) {
    console.log(output) // 'x'
  })
```

To make the example more clear:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')

Promise.resolve('y')
  .then(function (y) {
    // y == 'y'
    return 'c';
  })
  .then(function(c) {
    // c == 'c'
    return 'a';
  })
  .then(function(a) {
    // a == 'a'
    return 'b';
  })
  .then(function(b) {
    // b == 'b'
    return 'x';
  }).
  then(function(x) {
    console.log(x);  // output is 'x';
  });
```

Comment: so for example, the Promise.resolve('b') in the first example could be replaced with another promise such as a file read and that code would still return x?

Comment: Correct.  We are logging the final value of the promise only, and that value is set by the line `return 'x'`;

Comment: @threeve: *"I believe that a promise can only be resolved once. The rest will be ignored."* That's true, but irrelevant; none of the promises in the OP's code is being settled more than once.

Answer (score 4):

The point of a promise chain is that it allows `then` callbacks to transform the result, which is what you're seeing. If you *don't* want to transform the result, you have to return the value your `then` callback received in order to propagate it, or keep using the original promise instead of using the one returned by `then`.

Remember that `then` *creates* a promise, which is resolved based on what you return from the `then` callback. So there's no need for most if not all of those `Promise.resolve` calls.

A couple of simple examples (requires `Promise` support in your browser):

```js
// Prints:
//    First callback got a
//    Second callback got A
Promise.resolve("a")
  .then(function(value) {
    console.log("First callback got " + value);
    return value.toUpperCase();
  })
  .then(function(value) {
    console.log("Second callback got " + value);
    return value.toUpperCase();
  });

// Contrast that with using the same promise for both `then` calls:
// Prints:
//    Third callback got a
//   Fourth callback got a
setTimeout(function() {
  var p = Promise.resolve("a");
  p.then(function(value) {
    console.log("Third callback got " + value);
    return value.toUpperCase();
  });
  p.then(function(value) {
    console.log("Fourth callback got " + value);
    return value.toUpperCase();
  });
}, 100);
```